# Access HTML of DOM element?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

With Vue 2 I have this in my template:

```
<table ref="test">
    ....
</table>
```

When I get this via `this.$refs.test` I get `[object HTMLTableElement]` is there a way to return the actual HTML?

Comment: Not a duplicate.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with this `test` ref? Print it?

Comment: Perhaps `this.$refs.test.innerHTML` (or `outerHTML`)?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what's your purpose in doing this, but if you want to be able to for example display it's `outerHTML` you have to check if `this.$refs.test` exists and if it does - render it. This is because `refs` aren't reactive so using `computed` properties won't work.

```
<pre v-if="!!$refs.test">{{$refs.test.outerHTML}}</pre>
```

If you want to set it's `outerHTML` to a property or use `querySelector` or any other DOM operation on it, you need to wait for your component to be `mounted`.

```
mounted() {
    this.testRowContent = this.$refs.test.querySelector('.test').innerHTML;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/323125/